Forecasting Resource Depletion in a Distributed System
I manage a distributed system where each node contains six interchangeable resource slots, sourced from a diverse pool of resource types. Each type has a finite number of units, which get consumed until depletion. My primary objective is to predict the depletion timing for these resources to enable reordering seven days before they run out. Additionally, I'm interested in optimizing resource allocation across nodes to influence mutual consumption rates, but I'll focus on this second goal later.
Currently, I'm addressing the prediction of when a resource will be depleted. I've reformulated this into a time series forecasting problem where I predict daily consumption for each resource on a specific node. To estimate the depletion time for resource X, I continuously subtract the predicted daily consumption from the current stock until it reaches zero.
Factors like holidays, weather, and the presence of other resources influence consumption, adding complexity to the forecasting.
I've experimented with Facebook Prophet for initial modeling but am considering more sophisticated approaches due to the unique challenges of our system:

Multivariate Time Series Forecasting: Creating individual forecasting models for each resource at each node, considering external variables.
Panel Time Series Forecasting: Developing a unified model that applies across all nodes and resource types.

Challenges I'm facing include:

Choosing the Best Forecasting Approach: Between multivariate and panel time series forecasting, which is more suitable, or is there a better alternative?
Handling Data Gaps Due to Resource Rotation: For instance, if slot 1 switches from resource A to B and back to A, the absence of A isn't due to zero consumption but because B was in place. How should I account for these gaps when A is absent, especially to predict what consumption would have been if A had been continuously present?
Model Retraining: What strategies should I consider for effectively retraining the models to adapt to changes in resource usage patterns?
Evaluation Strategy: What metrics and methods should I use to ensure model accuracy, particularly in the critical week before a resource is expected to run out?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on tackling these issues!
